# How to calculate standard deviation over a range of dates when there are dates missing in pyspark 2.2.0

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark df wherein I am using a combination of windows + udf function to calculate standard deviation over historical business dates. The challenge is that my df is missing dates when there is no transaction. How do I calculate std dev including these missing dates without adding them as additional rows into my df to limit the df size going out of memory.

Sample Table & Current output

```
| ID | Date     | Amount | Std_Dev|
|----|----------|--------|--------|
|1   |2021-03-24| 10000  |        |
|1   |2021-03-26|  5000  |        |
|1   |2021-03-29| 10000  |2886.751|
```

Current Code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,first,Window,withColumn
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date")

workdaysUDF = F.udf(lambda date1, date2: int(np.busday_count(date2, date1)) if (date1 is not None and date2 is not None) else None, IntegerType()) # UDF to calculate difference between business days#

df = df.withColumn("date_dif", workdaysUDF(F.col('Date'), F.first(F.col('Date')).over(windowSpec))) #column calculating business date diff#

windowval = lambda days: Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date_dif').rangeBetween(-days, 0)

df = df.withColumn("std_dev",F.stddev("amount").over(windowval(6))\
        .drop("date_dif")
```

Desired Output where the values of dates missing between 24 to 29 March are being substituted with 0.

```
| ID | Date     | Amount | Std_Dev|
|----|----------|--------|--------|
|1   |2021-03-24| 10000  |        |
|1   |2021-03-26|  5000  |        |
|1   |2021-03-29| 10000  |4915.96 |
```

Please note that I am only showing std dev for a single date for illustration, there would be value for each row as I am using a rolling windows function.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Pyspark version is 2.2.0 at enterprise so I do not have flexibility to change the version.

Thanks,
VSG